# Wsdl to PHP: Can't import schema error for xml-exc-c14n

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I am trying to generate a php file from a wsdl file using wsdl2php.php script.
Previously when I was not using WS-Security in SOAP Service, everything was fine.

Everytime when I run the script, I am getting the error:

`PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#'`

I dont know whether any php library or package is missing or not...
Can anyone help me out?

My wsdl file looks like:

```
<types>

 <schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/myService.xsd"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:c14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
  xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
  xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
  xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
  xmlns:myService="http://tempuri.org/myService.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  elementFormDefault="unqualified"
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
  <import namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" schemaLocation="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"/>
  <import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"/>
  <import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
  <import namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" schemaLocation="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"/>
  <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
....
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to open the url `http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#`in your browser? You'll see that it points to a webpage and not a schema as the next one `http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd` does.
In any case, using wsdl2php or [WsdlToPhp](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) will fire you this error.

Comment: Then can we say that gSOAP has some bug because the wsdl file is generated by soapcpp2 executable? We do not have any control over it.

Comment: Yes, it might come from gSOAP. How do you declare which schemas have to be included in your WSDL? Are you able to specify which schema have to be included?

Comment: Actually, I am using WS-Security Plugin for which I need to include wsse.h in my input header file to soapcpp2. I saw wsse.h in turn includes c14n.h. And I finally get the wsdl file with the above schema locations.